# Emulator on Android Studio and Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, android-emulator, hyper-v, haxm

i think i have a huge problem...actually I'n developing on Android and Windows Phone, first with Android Studio i dont have nay problems... but with de WP emulator (VS Express 2012 SDK) I have problems with de Hyper-V... I update my OS to Windows 8.1 to solve it...but now Android I have problems with Studio emulator!!  is this :

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

ok.. it's fine...but one solution is to reinstall the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) but when i made this i have to disable de Hyper-V!!! so not WP emulator! What can i do to work the both emulators????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the Windows Phone emulator requires Hyper-V to be enabled, which is incompatible with AVD using Intel HAXM. There are two options:

1. Use the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx), which can
   connect to your Android Studio project via ADB (build your APK and
   adb.exe push) and is a Hyper-V-based, x86 emulator, so it can run
   side-by-side with the Windows Phone emulator.
2. Enable/disable Hyper-V whenever you switch between platforms (this requires a reboot every time you go from WP -> Android or vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

can you just switch per boot - the two commands would be
*bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off*
*bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto*  or you could use *net start hvboot*